# Moxa NPort 5210A Functioning

Tags: serial-port, device, ethernet

I need advice on this product Moxa NPort 5120A I use to convert the serial outputs of some ethernet cards in order to be able to connect to the network.
Using the Realcom Mode, but whenever I connect it to your network and want to use a software from the PC to control it I need to open the software NPort Administrator, add the device, and then open the Web console, otherwise the doors do not appear to be open and if I do not open the web console software NPort Administrator (with the appropriate button) and I type the IP address of the port in the browser always comes back to me that the server is not responding and I do not load the web page. Has anyone had experience with the Moxa and their products? And 'it possible to use this module that I always have to open the software and open the Web console without having to change any settings to enable the COM port?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Normally with these types of devices you use TCP/IP sockets for communication with the device(s) on the other end. In your application you create a socket and listen for connections. Once a connection is made you process the data coming in and send data out to the device.

You also configure the device on the other end to tell it to connect to a specific IP address/port which is the server or PC running your software which is listening for the connection.

It sounds like that device also offers a device driver that can be installed and causes it to emulate a serial port. In that case, you would configure it that way and have your application open a serial port and communicate with the device as if it were actually attached to a real serial (COM) port.